What is the basis for ones life decided by ones own karma?
It looks good to hear that every action has a good or bad reaction in the universe.
But what is the concept behind my actions have reaction on me only?
I know consciousness that exists everywhere in the universe stores all information, but what is the believable reasoning behind those reactions stored in consciousness will impact doer only
